# "EXECUTE" function within trigger not functioning in TSQL on SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

This is my code I am attempting to run inside a trigger.  In a trigger it fails because of the EXEC line.  I know this because when I take it out, the code at least finishes execution.  If I leave it in it, it doesn't even bother finishing.  I know this because if I take out the exec line, it will write the sql line to the error table.

I have to use an EXEC command here to write to the remote server.  I can't use a nvarchar variable to define the server.  Insert expects an explicit table or a table variable.  I need to be able to write to this remote server AND I don't know the name of it until runtime, so I can't be explicit.  How do I use an EXEC inside a trigger or is there another way to skin this cat?

```
DECLARE @acctNum int
DECLARE @tickets nvarchar(MAX)
DECLARE @server nvarchar(64)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
if EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.queueNames WHERE queueName = 'queue1')
BEGIN
  SELECT @server = queueServer FROM dbo.queueNames WHERE queueName = 'queue1'
  SET @server = @server + '.[AMEETING].dbo.tblMembers'
  SELECT TOP 1 @acctNum = AccountNum, @tickets = Tickets FROM dbo.queue1 ORDER BY AccountNum
  SET @sql = 'UPDATE ' + @server + ' SET Present = ''1'', Tickets = ''' + @tickets + ''' WHERE AccountNum = ' + convert(nvarchar(64),@acctNum)
  INSERT INTO dbo.errors values (@sql)
  EXEC (@sql)
  DELETE FROM dbo.queue1 WHERE AccountNum = @acctNum
END
```

Comment: have you tried using exec sp_executesql @sql?

Comment: Hard to say, I can't find anything specifically prohibiting the exec call in a trigger. It could be the server name contains a character that needs to be escaped, or that the server name is also specifying a schema. Wrap it in a TRY/CATCH and use some of the example [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179296(v=sql.105).aspx#code-snippet-2) to log to your errors table to figure it out.

Comment: You are using a four-part identifier for the target table. The MSDN doc for `EXEC` [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.105).aspx) has a couple of notes about 'Context Switching' which may be why it is failing. Also, obvious question - does the user who triggers the trigger have permissions to update a table on the remote server? Most likely not, unless using Windows auth and the same network. I'm not sure if you can use `OPENROWSET` or `OPENQUERY` from a trigger, but it might be an alternate solution.

Comment: I've attempted to circumvent this by just hardcoding the server directly into the code so I don't have to exec it.  It still fails, though if I remove the trigger, it makes it to the table.  The trigger fails and doesn't pass the update to the other computer :(

Answer (score 0):

I am giving up on this and have gone with using text files on the local server and running processes in the background there to queue the sql statements.